# SQL how to get max valued row from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

My use case is something like this.

1. I have restaurants.
2. One restaurants has many restaurant items.
3. Each restaurant item has a rating value.

I want to get restaurants along with the top rated item for that restaurant.

I pseudo query will be something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM RESTAURANTS 
WHERE RESTAURANT_IDS = 1,2,3,4,5 
LEFT JOIN RESTAURANT_ITEMS 
WHERE ratings = MAX(ratings)
```

in RESTAURANTS table.

```
id|name
-------------
1 |McDonalds
2 |Pizzahut
3 |Buger king
4 |KFC
```

in RESTAURANT_ITEMS table

```
id|name      |rating| FK_RES_ID
----------------------------
1 |Pizza     |5     |2
2 |Lava cake |4     |2
3 |Veg burger|3     |4
4 |Chicken b |5.6   |4
5 |Ice cream |4.3   |1
6 |Burger    |5     |1
```

Desired output would be

```
id|name      |top item
----------------------
1 |McDonalds |Burger
2 |Pizzahut  |Pizza
3 |Buger king|Null
4 |KFC       |Chicken b
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your select statement wrong.. Left do evaluation in from not in where clause..

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @dwir182 this is a pseudo code. I want to pass restaurant ids and want to get back the restaurant with it's top rated item.

Comment: Pseudo code will help people to clear what are they trying to do.. But i clearly don't get the point what you want to do.. Read link @Strawberry gave to you..

Comment: @dwir182 my apologies. i update the question.

Comment: @PathumSamararathna what if there are multiple items with top rating for a restaurant ? Will you fetch all of them, or any one of them ?

Comment: @dwir182 restaurant McDonalds id = 1 items would be ice cream, burger, pepsi cola. Top rated one would be burger.

Comment: @PathumSamararathna can you show us sample data? and desired result will really help

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya apologies I update my question.

Comment: @Strawberry I update my question.

Comment: @dwir182 I update my question.

Comment: @PathumSamararathna please answer the question about possibility of having duplicate items with same ratings. What would  you get then ? Also, what is your MySQL server version ? Depending on the version, there may be a trivial solution available.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya there won't be any duplicate items. One restaurant can have one pizza and Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you are looking for. Try and confirm. :)

```
SELECT 
      res.ResName
      ,item.Name as ResItem
      ,(Select max(SubItem.rating) from RESTAURANT_ITEMS SubItem where res.RestaurantID= SubItem.RestaurantID) as Rating
FROM 
      RESTAURANTS res
LEFT JOIN 
      RESTAURANT_ITEMS item on res.RestaurantID = item.RestaurantID
WHERE 
      res.Restaurant_ID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

**EDITED PART BELOW AFTER QUESTION WAS ALSO UPDATED**

```
SELECT 
      res.Name as [Restaurant Name]
      ,item.Name as [Top Item]
FROM 
      RESTAURANTS res
LEFT JOIN 
      RESTAURANT_ITEMS item on res.RestaurantID = item.RestaurantID 
                            and rating = (select max(subItems.rating) from RESTAURANT_ITEMS subItems where subItems.RestaurantID = res.RestaurantID)
WHERE 
      res.Restaurant_ID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Hope this helps you now :)

Comment: @PathumSamararathna updated my answer and shared the logic

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the highest rating value in a Derived Table, for a Restaurant.
- Join it back to main tables to get the desired output

Try the following:

```
SELECT r.id, 
       r.name, 
       ri.name AS top_item 
FROM RESTAURANTS AS r 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_RES_ID, MAX(rating) AS max_rating 
           FROM RESTAURANT_ITEMS 
           GROUP BY FK_RES_ID) AS dt 
  ON dt.FK_RES_ID = r.id 
LEFT JOIN RESTAURANT_ITEMS AS ri ON ri.FK_RES_ID = dt.FK_RES_ID AND 
                                    ri.rating = dt.max_rating 

WHERE r.id IN (1,2,3,4)
```